# Onclick show/hide div & img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I am trying to do.

**I am trying to have **>** Arrow onclick SHOW the sidebar**.

**On click** it will also **hide the > arrow.**

**Once the sidebar DIV is shown -- Show **<** Arrow.**

**On click; Hide < and Hide DIV.**

Then

When Mobile is activated --

**Move the arrows to the top & rotate 90 degrees to show ^ and v to show/hide the div bar..**

```
<div style="display:none" id="sbar" class="sbar">
        <div class='arrowhide' style="display:sbarhide" id="toggleoff"> <a href="#" onclick="sbarhide('sbar')"><img id='arrow'src='http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20141216054306/crusader-quest-th/images/d/d8/Left-arrow-right-hi.png' height="65" width="35"></img>
     </div>  
    <nav class="sidebar"> <a class="Logo" href="#">
      <span class="icons act fsize"></span>
    </a>
 <div class="links">
            <ul class="nav of aox">
                <li> <a href="#" title="Home" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-container="body">
            <span class="icons abw"></span>
            <small class="linkfsize sa">Home</small>
          </a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="#" title="List" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-container="body">
            <span class="icons aie"></span>
            <small class="linkfsize sa">List</small>
          </a>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#" title="Map" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-container="body">
            <span class="icons abh"></span>
            <small class="linkfsize sa">Map</small>
          </a>
                </li>
                <li class="active"> <a href="#" title="Stats" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-container="body">
            <span class="icons vd"></span>
            <small class="linkfsize sa">Stats</small>
          </a>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#" title="Docs" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-container="body">
            <span class="icons ade"></span>
            <small class="linkfsize sa">Docs</small>
          </a>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#" title="Logout" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-container="body">
            <span class="icons adk"></span>
            <small class="linkfsize sa">Logout</small>
          </a>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#" title="Signed in as User First & Last Name" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-container="body">
            <img src="http://bootstrap-themes.github.io/dashboard/assets/img/avatar-mdo.png" alt="" class="cs cn">
            <small class="linkfsize sa">@mdo</small>
          </a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class='arrowshow' style="display:sbarshow" id="toggleon">  <a href="#" onclick="sbarshow('sbar')"><img id='arrow'src='http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20141216054306/crusader-quest-th/images/d/d8/Left-arrow-right-hi.png' height="65" width="35"></img>
     </div>    

<script>
function sbarshow(target) {
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
}

function sbarhide(target) {
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'none';
}
        </script>
```

CSS

```
.arrowshow {
    padding-left: 2.5%;
    opacity: 0.1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.arrowhide {

    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 2;    
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);     /* Chrome and other webkit browsers */
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);        /* FF */
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);          /* Opera */
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);         /* IE9 */
    transform: rotate(180deg);             /* W3C compliant browsers */
}
/* SIDEBAR */
 .sidebar {
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .sidebar {
        overflow: hidden position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 70px;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        background-color: #30343e;
        overflow-y: auto;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .sbar {
        padding-left: 85px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .links {
        overflow: auto;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
}
/* SIDEBAR END */

/* LOGO Section */
 .Logo {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #6f7890;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #0f1013;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .Logo {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
}
.Logo:hover {
    color: #cfd2da;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* pinAPP Logo Section END */

/* Sidebar FONT SIZE */
 .fsize {
    font-size: 30px;
}
.linkfsize {
    font-size: 14px;
}
/* Sidebar FONT Size END */

/* Sidebar ICONS */
 .icons:before {
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family:"toolkit-entypo";
    speak: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
/* Sidebar ICONS END */
```

VISIT THE FIDDLE HERE TO SEE WHAT I AM TALKING ABOUT.

http://jsfiddle.net/LZoesch/1x809wbf/

@levizoesch
As my edit changes your post without your permission, i am adding it as update so update your post if this is what you wanted to ask else just remove this part.

**Update :**

I have a sidebar , by default that is hidden. I have a  right arrow . when user clicks on that then the sidebar is shown and left arrow is shown which is used to hide the same side bar. arrows are at middle (vertical) of the screen now.

Now When i open this in mobile i want these arrows to be moved to the top of the screen and should be visible like up and down arrows instead of left and right arrows. How to do this ?

Comment: Show the efforts to solve the problem.

Comment: I have tried a various of things, and I cannot get it. If you can add value to my question then please help...

Comment: Okay, add the failed attempts in the question

Comment: Tried Z-index, tried repositioning the div's...

Comment: @levizoesch look man, we're all here to help, that's why we bothered clicking on your question. But it doesn't help when you copy/paste your entire code. No one has time to look through it. You need to take out everything that isn't relevant to your specific issue so we can get to the answer faster. And when you have script tags in your html, separate that into a javascript section instead of sticking it in with the html.

Comment: @RayonDabre I didnt paste my entire code. I pasted what is NEEDED only. I edited my question to give you SOLID points as to what I am trying to do. I dont know how else to explain it............

Comment: @AbdulAhmad this is not a helpful solution to my issue...

Comment: @levizoesch check the updated part of your post, if that is what you wanted to explain then update your post else delete that part .

Comment: @levizoesch This time you took away too much code. Can you add it back? Ha jk... :P

Comment: and you can achieve this in `@media (max-width: 768px) {` css block . just write code for rotating and moving the div to top.